# Monitoring rabbitmq (v 3.6.8) with prometheus

Tags: rabbitmq, prometheus

I have a challenge - build and release monitoring system in consist of RabbitMQ cluster (with 3 nodes) and standalone Grafana server for visualisation metrics.

I have found in official documentation of prometheus plugin for RabbitMQ ([documentation](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-prometheus)) next section:

> This plugin is new as of RabbitMQ 3.8.0.

But i have cluster of version 3.6.8 and when i run the next command

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_prometheus
```

The output is:

> Error: The following plugins could not be found:
>     rabbitmq_prometheus

Upgrade the cluster now is not possible and my question is:

How do i may configure monitoring of the cluster without upgrade it and with prometheus (preferred option) and grafana?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Prometheus plugin is not the only way to monitor a RabbitMQ cluster.

You can also use the [rabbitmq exporter](https://github.com/kbudde/rabbitmq_exporter) in sidecar. If you are not on a docker platform, you can download the exporter [from the release assets](https://github.com/kbudde/rabbitmq_exporter/releases) and install it as a service somewhere.

It would be best to install the exporter on every server hosting the RabbitMQ node because:

- you will need to have as many install as there are nodes (Prometheus is service oriented monitoring)
- from [the settings](https://github.com/kbudde/rabbitmq_exporter#settings), the exporter is accessing the [management plugin interface](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html) of RabbitMQ; it should stay bound to localhost to reduce attack surface

If your hands are really tied, you can deploy them anywhere (let say on the same server) and point each exporter to a different RabbitMQ node. Prometheus configuration can then identify the underlying service.

```
  - job_name: rabbitmq
    honor_labels: true
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['monitoring-server:97001']
        labels:
          instance: 'rabbitmq_node_A'
      - targets: ['monitoring-server:97002']
        labels:
          instance: 'rabbitmq_node_B'
      # or play with relabeling to acchieve the same.
```

An important drawback is that there are more cases where the exporter may not be able to access RabbitMQ and you end up alert on events not impacting your RabbitMQ cluster.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have read about this plugin. Unfortunately, i don't have cluster in docker and migrate cluster to docker is not possible now.

Comment: Well you don't need docker to use it. Simply grab the [release](https://github.com/kbudde/rabbitmq_exporter/releases) and launch it on the same server as the RabbitMQ node. You can even launch it on another server but it means exposing management URL.

Comment: It sounds great. Thank you. I wil try!