# Spring JMS, custom event listener to identify when messages are added or removed from specific queues

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, event-handling, jms

I've got a spring app that uses multiple queues to handle event processing. The app adds messages to these queues when specific events occur. When the messages are consumed they are removed implicitly. Example : `RETRY_QUEUE` to reprocess the message `SUCCESS_QUEUE` if the message gets through processing.

Internally I use `@JmsListner` to monitor the queue for incoming messages, how do I create a custom event handler that can be used to publish events when messages are added or removed from these queues ? I wanted to monitor these queues using prometheus gauges by `inc()` or `dec()` the queue size based on enqueue or dequeue events.

Comment: you can keep counters in your @JmsListener functions and call/trigger prometheus gauges like https://stackoverflow.com/a/65239646/175554 or better approach would be monitor the queues from source directly like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/60197667/175554

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring AOP principles to create point cuts to the `JmsListener.onMessage()` and `JmsTemplate.send(..)` methods to publish events. This approach will decouple your business logic with your event publish logic.

See also : `@After`, `@Before`, `@AfterReturning`, etc advices.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/reference/aop.html